# Incremento en DataTable

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo esta `dataTable` con un top de productos mas vendidos, pero no quiero que me de el id de la tabla, sino un loop de 1 a 10, como lo podría hacer? aca tengo mi código:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php if(!empty($productosmvendidos)):?>
      <?php foreach($productosmvendidos as $pmv):?>
        <tr>
          <?php $i=1;?>
          <td><?php echo $i+=1;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $pmv->nombre;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $pmv->categoria;?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
  <?php endif;?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Aca la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: intenta declarar una variable antes del foreach y dentro del for le agregas un ++

Comment: Como haces la sentencia sql ? desde ahi seria mas facil, traer todo como quieres y luego no piensas en mas. Muestrame la sentencia sql profavor

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, gracias @Rastalovely aca dejo la respuesta:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Categoria</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php if(!empty($productosmvendidos)):?>
                                <?php $i=1;?>
                                <?php foreach($productosmvendidos as $pmv):?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $i++;?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $pmv->nombre;?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $pmv->categoria;?></td>

                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de nada me ganaste, ya estaba escribiendo la respuesta. Saludos